# Adicionar valores a uma base de dados por PHP

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Eu estou a tentar adicionar valores a uma base de dados através de PHP. Estou a utilizar PHPMyAdmin para ambas as bases de dados e tambem para o site em questão.

Neste momento o código que eu tenho é o seguinte, apresento as minhas dúvidas no final:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle_inserir.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="w3schoolsExample.css">

        <title>Inserir utilizador</title>
        <style>
            form label{
                display: inline-block;
                width: 100px;
                font-weight: bold;   
            }       
        </style> 
    </head>
<body>

        <?php

            $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "root";
            $password = "";
            $dbname = "rhumanos";
        
            // Create connection
            $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

            // Check connection
            if (!$conn) {
                die("Conecção falhou: " . mysqli_connect_error() );
            }
            echo "Conectado";
            
            function addToDB(){

                $nome = $_POST['nome'];
                $cargo = $_POST['cargo'];
                $email = $_POST['email'];
                $localidade = $_POST['localidade'];
                $setor = $_POST['setor'];   
                $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
                $salario = $_POST['salario'];
                $horario = $_POST['horario'];
        
                $sql = "INSERT INTO trabalhador (nome, cargo, email, localidade, setor, telefone, salario, horario) 
                VALUES ($nome, $cargo, $email, $localidade, $setor, $telefone, $salario, $horario)";

                if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
                    echo "Adicionado com sucesso";
                } else {
                    echo "Erro: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
                }
                mysqli_close($conn);
            }    
        ?>
    
    <h2>Exemplo de inserção numa MySQL database ao usar PHP</h2>

        <br><br>

        <form action="addToDB()" method="post">
            <label for="nome">Nome: </label>                          <input type="text" name="nome" />
            <br><br>
            <label for="cargo">Cargo: </label>                        <input type="text" name="cargo" />
            <br><br>
            <label for="email">E-Mail: </label>                       <input type="text" name="email" />
            <br><br>
            <label for="localidade">Localidade: </label>              <input type="text" name="localidade" />
            <br><br>
            <label for="setor">Setor de Trabalho: </label>            <input type="text" name="setor" />
            <br><br>
            <label for="telefone">Telefone: </label>                  <input type="text" name="telefone" />
            <br><br>
            <label for="salario">Salario (/h): </label>               <input type="text" name="salario" />
            <br><br>
            <label for="horario">Horário (QT horas): </label>         <input type="text" name="horario" />
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Eu neste momento estou a ter 2 problemas...

1º Eu quero que, ao clickar no meu botão Submit, a função addToDB() seja executada e neste momento não entendo o processo de como o fazer.

2º Eu já tentei sem usar função e o server devolveu-me um erro de formato, eu sei que tem a ver com os dados que eu coloquei.

Os dados do tipo VARCHAR precisam de ser formatados da seguinte maneira:

-> "Nome de funcionario", entre aspas para ser aceite

e eu estou simplesmente a adicionar

-> dado, sem formatação e não sei como corrigir isso.

O objetivo é simplesmente adicionar os dados que coloquei [nesta imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13rKM.png) na base de dados e não estou a conseguir.

Desde já obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1º Eu quero que, ao clickar no meu botão Submit, a função addToDB() seja executada e neste momento não entendo o processo de como o fazer.

Seu código está todo misturado. A função do *PHP* não vai rodar no cliente. Você deve criar uma página *PHP* pra tratar os dados do seu formulário e colocar no action do seu *form*:

**index.php**:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle_inserir.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="w3schoolsExample.css">

        <title>Inserir utilizador</title>
        <style>
            form label{
                display: inline-block;
                width: 100px;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h2>Exemplo de inserção numa MySQL database ao usar PHP</h2>

            <br><br>

            <form action="form.php" method="post">
                <label for="nome">Nome: </label>                          <input type="text" name="nome" />
                <br><br>
                <label for="cargo">Cargo: </label>                        <input type="text" name="cargo" />
                <br><br>
                <label for="email">E-Mail: </label>                       <input type="text" name="email" />
                <br><br>
                <label for="localidade">Localidade: </label>              <input type="text" name="localidade" />
                <br><br>
                <label for="setor">Setor de Trabalho: </label>            <input type="text" name="setor" />
                <br><br>
                <label for="telefone">Telefone: </label>                  <input type="text" name="telefone" />
                <br><br>
                <label for="salario">Salario (/h): </label>               <input type="text" name="salario" />
                <br><br>
                <label for="horario">Horário (QT horas): </label>         <input type="text" name="horario" />
                <br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="submit">
            </form>

    </body>

</html>
```

**form.php**:

```
    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Conecção falhou: " . mysqli_connect_error() );
    }
    // echo "Conectado";

    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $cargo = $_POST['cargo'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $localidade = $_POST['localidade'];
    $setor = $_POST['setor'];
    $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
    $salario = $_POST['salario'];
    $horario = $_POST['horario'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO trabalhador (nome, cargo, email, localidade, setor, telefone, salario, horario)
    VALUES ($nome, $cargo, $email, $localidade, $setor, $telefone, $salario, $horario)";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "Adicionado com sucesso";
    } else {
        echo "Erro: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

> Os dados do tipo VARCHAR precisam de ser formatados da seguinte maneira:
>   -> "Nome de funcionario", entre aspas para ser aceite

Basta atualizar a sua *query*:

```
// ...
$sql = "INSERT INTO trabalhador (nome, cargo, email, localidade, setor, telefone, salario, horario)
VALUES ('$nome', '$cargo', '$email', '$localidade', '$setor', '$telefone', '$salario', '$horario')";
// ...
```

Vale a pena lembrar que dessa forma seu sistema fica *BEEEM* vulnerável. Melhor forma de executar tais consultas (quando vem dados de algum *input*) é utilizando os chamados [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)...

Lembrando: *PHP* é rodado no servidor. *HTML* é rodado no cliente. Isso significa que você não pode chamar uma *function* do *PHP* no *HTML*...